# get child from multidimensional array based on value php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i'm working on a project where i have a structured object like this:

```
$main_array=   [
  [
    "key"=> "home",
    "value":=> "Go Home!"
  ],

  [
    "key"=> "business",
    "value"=> "Go to Work!"
  ],

  [
    "key"=> "other",
    "value"=> "Go where you want!"
  ]
]
```

i'd like to know if there is a way to retrieve the object based on the "key" parameter. 
What i want to do is "extract" the nested array like

```
$home_array=["key"=> "home","value":=> "Go Home!"]
```

and so on for "business" and "others".
in javascript, i can use jquery or underscore to get what i want, is there a php method to achieve this, or something to simulate a "where" clause in a multidimensional array/object?

thak you in advance

Comment: why not build the array such that the key is actually the key?

Comment: My advice for you is to use arrays the way they were meant to be used, not the way you are using them now.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily convert the array you have to have the 'key' column to be the main index using `array_column()`...

```
$main_array=   [
        [
                "key"=> "home",
                "value"=> "Go Home!"
        ],

        [
                "key"=> "business",
                "value"=> "Go to Work!"
        ],

        [
                "key"=> "other",
                "value"=> "Go where you want!"
        ]
];

$out = array_column($main_array, null, "key");

print_r($out['business']);
```

Outputs...

```
Array
(
    [key] => business
    [value] => Go to Work!
)
```

Comment: looking around the web i found a similar solution, but seems to not work in my case. ASAP, i'll post the current code (the original array is a protected array from a contact class in EWS)

Comment: One thing to note is that in your original post, there is one element with `:=> ` which is incorrect.

Comment: yes @nigel, i know that. i wrote it in plain text ;)

Answer (score 1):

A few possibilities to get a single item matching a specific key:

1. Iterate the main array and stop when you get to a child that has the proper key:

   ```
   $object = (function($key) use($main_array) {
       foreach ($main_array as $object) {
           if ($object['key'] == $key) return $object;
       }
   })('business');
   ```

   (This example uses an anonymous function, but you can just use a simple foreach loop and break when you find the key.)
2. Reindex the main array and look up the child by key:

   ```
   $indexed = array_column($main_array, null, 'key');

   $object = $indexed['business'];
   ```
3. Construct the array using the key as the index to begin with. Using string keys doesn't preclude the array elements being other arrays that can contain multiple values.

   ```
   $main_array=   [
     'home' => ["value"=> "Go Home!"],
     'business' => ["value"=> "Go to Work!"],
     'other' => ["value"=> "Go where you want!"]
   ];
   ```

Methods 2 and 3 require that they key is unique. Method 1 doesn't, but it will just return the first instance it finds.

If you do have multiple instances of a key, you probably want `array_filter`. This will work more like the "where clause" you referred to.

```
$key = 'home';
$filtered = array_filter($main_array, function($item) use ($key) {
    return $item['key'] == $key;
});
```

This will return multiple items instead of just one.